# MRO in Python doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

I found an example of multiple inheritance but don't understand the way it behaves.

```
class Printable:
    """A mixin class for creating a __str__ method that prints
    a sequence object. Assumes that the type difines __getitem__."""

    def lef_bracket(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + "["

    def right_bracket(self):
        return "]"

    def __str__(self):
        result = self.lef_bracket()
        for i in range(len(self)-1):
            result += str(self[i]) + ", "
        if len(self) > 0:
            result += str(self[-1])
        return result + self.right_bracket()
```

This script is stored in *printable.py* so the class `Printable` is used in this way:

```
>>> from printable import *
>>> class MySeq(list, Printable):
...     pass
... 
>>> my_seq = MySeq([1,2,3])
>>> print(my_seq)
MySeq[1, 2, 3]
```

My question is that why the `__str__` method is inherited from the `Printable` class instead of the `list` class, while the Method Resolution Order of `MySeq` is:

```
>>> MySeq.__mro__
(<class '__main__.MySeq'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'printable.Printable'>, <class 'object'>)
```

In the docstring of `Printable` I notice the word "mixin". Why in this case we call it a mixin class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` doesn't define a `__str__` method:

```
>>> '__str__' in list.__dict__
False
```

Because it doesn't define such a method, the next class in the MRO gets to supply it. For a plain `list` object, that'd be `object.__str__`:

```
>>> list.__mro__
(<class 'list'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> list.__str__ is object.__dict__['__str__']
True
```

but because `Printable` is mixed in, it is listed **before** `object`:

```
>>> MySeq.__mro__
(<class '__main__.MySeq'>, <class 'list'>, <class '__main__.Printable'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> MySeq.__str__ is Printable.__dict__['__str__']
True
```

A mix-in class is a class designed to be added into a class hierarchy to work together with other base classes. `Printable` is a mix-in because it requires that something else implements `__getitem__`.